# Powershell query results list

Tags: powershell, powerquery

The Powershell script provides results table below. We need to find out if VM is reachable or not, so I would like to check if "Time" column is not empty.

The question:

How to check if "Time(ms)" has value? how to query any column or row in such a cases in general?

```
$result = Test-ConnectionAsync "MyVm"

C:\$result

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    --------
SourceVM        MyVM          10.20.20.10                                                32       207
SourceVM        MyVM          10.20.20.10                                                32       207
SourceVM        MyVM          10.20.20.10                                                32       207
SourceVM        MyVM          10.20.20.10                                                32       207
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Where-Object` functionality that checks the value of any column of the given row. If you want to find out what column names are supposed to be, use `Get-Member` to get all the properties or methods of that object.

```
# Get all the properties of $result[0]
$result[0] | Get-Member

# Among other things, you will ResponseTime as one of the properties you can use.

# Check if Time(ms) has any value. Following will give you only those rows that match the condition

#Original where statement
#$result | Where-Object { $_.ResponseTime -ne $null }

#Updated where statement
$result | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.ResponseTime }
```

Comment: Nice. Even though it makes no difference here, it's a good habit to form in PowerShell to use `$null` as the _LHS_ in `-eq` / `-ne` comparisons - e.g., `$null -eq $var` instead of `$var -eq $null` - because if the LHS happens to be an _array_, the RHS value acts a _filter_ rather than returning a Boolean. E.g., `1, $null, 2 -ne $null` returns array `1, 2`, not `$true`.

Comment: that is amazing. Moving the elements around the comparison operator changes the results altogether. I will definitely keep that in mind !!

Comment: Glad to hear it. The behavior is both powerful and a common pitfall; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators?view=powershell-7 now mentions it (including the recommendation to place `$null` on the LHS), but could do a better job of highlighting it.